# What causes journal logs to end with tilde (~)?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-journald, journalctl

Many of my journal log files consistently are named ending with tilde, e.g. -

```
/var/log/journal/dc104498c02e4392903c4b68c856a662 $ ls -ltrh
total 768M
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 8.0M Jun 11 11:59 system@0005e130a3f4ba41-1a5b3de36e6e1a83.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 8.0M Jun 11 12:08 system@0005e130c31fa149-a264e2fef5695fe3.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 8.0M Jun 11 12:10 system@0005e130cbc7ce3e-afe601ad1d2f7384.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 8.0M Jun 11 12:16 system@0005e130e260ab6c-8cbee483baad4441.journal~
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  16M Jun 12 11:19 system@0005e14434aa7963-71677f727f29b453.journal~
...
```

They also happen to be always multiples of 8M in size.

What might cause this?

I suspect the files may be incomplete, but they seem to always end properly -

```
journalctl --file system@0005e130e260ab6c-8cbee483baad4441.journal~ | tail
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 audit: BPF prog-id=0 op=UNLOAD
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 kernel: audit: type=1334 audit(1654974990.059:192): prog-id=0 op=UNLOAD
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 audit: BPF prog-id=0 op=UNLOAD
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 systemd[1]: Using hardware watchdog 'iTCO_wdt', version 0, device /dev/watchdog0
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 systemd[1]: Watchdog running with a timeout of 10min.
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 kernel: watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 systemd-shutdown[1]: Using hardware watchdog 'iTCO_wdt', version 0, device /dev/watchdog0
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 systemd-shutdown[1]: Watchdog running with a timeout of 10min.
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Jun 11 12:16:30 z390 systemd-journald[569]: Journal stopped
```

Comment: Are these logs rotated by `logrotate` or some other log rotation software?

Comment: As a general line, tilde terminated filenames denote temporary files. Perhaps they're not being cleaned up for some reason? I'm not aware of the specifics of journald file management though.

Comment: Yes, `logrotate.timer` is in systemd which runs daily. But the clean split (the lines in ~ files always start with a boot, and ends at poweroff or reboot) makes me suspect it is something else that runs on reboot which causes them to be left like that.

Comment: Only files starting with `system@...` have this problem. There is no journal files starting with `user-1000@...` that end with `~`.

Comment: Traditionally in Unix-like systems files ending with a tilde are **backup** files. For example, most text editors use this convention.

Answer (score 1):

I have some user files with the ~ on them.

-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  25165824 Jan 29 13:01 user-1000@0005f36ae72da0ba-7cb185f012612eb1.journal~

-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jan 29 13:07 user-1000@0005f36afe061260-52662477b2f75a6c.journal~

-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal   8388608 Jan 29 13:20 user-1000@0005f36b2b96fdac-88e1fa9d097c4130.journal~

-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  67108864 Feb 19 20:27 user-1000@0005f5179ddf6fec-24a4126c2ac07df9.journal~

I am thinking when the computer freezes up and do a hard power reboot by holding the power button in for more than 5 seconds might cause these.