# What are the .journal files that have a ~ on the end?

Tags: systemd-journald, journalctl

I have some files in my `/var/log/journal/f7e928ba68a9449e85bd828252981fc6/` that have a `.journal~` extension.

Can I remove these?

example:

```
-rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  16777216 Dec 21 08:46 system@0005f056c84368b7-b723a71adb57a093.journal~
```

Can I delete these files?

Comment: I don't have a single file with this extension, probably there was an error when journald tried to rotate them. Maybe you ran out of free space or you had an IO error, no idea.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706233/what-causes-journal-logs-to-end-with-tilde

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man systemd-journald`:

> FILES
>
> > `/run/log/journal/machine-id/*.journal`, `/run/log/journal/machine-id/*.journal~`, `/var/log/journal/machine-id/*.journal`, `/var/log/journal/machine-id/*.journal~` 
> > **systemd-journald** writes entries to files in `/run/log/journal/machine-id/` or `/var/log/journal/machine-id/` with the `".journal"` suffix. If the daemon is stopped uncleanly, or if the files are found to be corrupted, they are renamed using the `".journal~"` suffix, and **systemd-journald** starts writing to a new file.
> > When systemd-journald ceases writing to a journal file, it will be renamed to "original-name@suffix.journal" (or "original-name@suffix.journal~"). Such
> > files are "archived" and will not be written to any more.

So basically as you can see above **systemd-journald** is writing these files when the files are corrupted or if the daemon is stopped *uncleanly*.

Regarding:

> Can I delete these files

As mentioned by user @intelfx you should remove these files if you are not interested in the journal logs provided by these files.

Also as mentioned by same user the files are still readable. You can, for example, read a journal file by using:

```bash
sudo journalctl --file /path/to/file.journal
sudo journalctl --file /path/to/file.journal~
```

Anyways, if you do not remove them, the  `systemd-journald` will automatically remove these files, as you can see in the same `man systemd-journald`:

> systemd-journald will automatically remove the oldest archived journal files to limit disk use. See SystemMaxUse= and related settings in journald.conf(5).

Comment: This answer is correct in stating the nature of the `.journal~` files; however, they can only be deleted "without any problem" if losing the corresponding logs is not considered a problem. These files contain unique data and `journalctl` will still read them; they are simply rotated to avoid appending to a file that might contain partial records at the end. I suggest that this answer is edited to remove the misleading statements at the end.

Comment: The journal files are designed to be readable even in case of a corruption; it is _writing_ to corrupted files that can be problematic. systemd could have included some sort of recovery code that repairs the journal files after an unclean shutdown; however it is simply much easier to rotate them because a corruption-resistant reader is easier to implement than a corruption-repairing writer.

Comment: @intelfx oh, that's useful! Man page did not mention that, (or maybe that's mentioned in another man page). I've updated the answer  accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There was an old bug related to [handling](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/src/libsystemd/sd-journal/sd-journal.c) files ending with a tilde but it has long been solved: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=58549

I don't have a single file with this extension, in your case probably there was an error when journald tried to rotate them. Maybe you ran out of free space, or you had an IO error, or the system rebooted unexpectedly.

Please restart journald and if the files are still there, it's safe to delete them:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

[Related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706233/what-causes-journal-logs-to-end-with-tilde).

Comment: Like my comment to the other answer says, it is only "safe" to delete those files if losing the corresponding logs is considered a "safe" situation.